# Tagging for a language used in explanation

Tags: discussion, tags

Often, a question asks:

> In language A, such and such can be done in such and such way or using this method/function. How can this be done in language B or what is the equivalent of this in language B?

and is tagged as both languages `A` and `B`. I think it should only be tagged as `B` since the question is about `B`, and the language `A` is used only to explain the concept that OP cannot without using it.

What do you think? Is there a consensus on this matter in stack overflow?

Comment: I'm not sure it really matters, most of these are "give me the codes" anyway, which calls for closure.

Comment: @Charles Not necessarily. A recent example I found is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822241/whats-the-javascript-equivalent-of-rubys-splat-operator

Answer (score 4):

Even if it's a bit confusing, I think such questions should be tagged with both languages' tags.

The reason behind it is, in my opinion, that you need to have a knowledge of both languages to answer the questions in a correct, meaningful way.  Also, people who later find the question should understand both languages to fully use the information contained in the question and answer.